# Trying to filter strings in list in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This code works, but NOT as expected. For example, typing: **red** displays "Red Hot Chili Peppers", but continuing with **red hot**, and it disappears. I am not sure, how a `new RegExp` should be applied in this code. I managed to come this far with the filtering.

```
query = "red hot";
const matches = [
    "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "Dua Lipa",
    "X&Y",
    "Viva la Vida or Death and All His Friends"
];

const lowercasedFilter = query.toLowerCase();
  const filtered = matches.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
      typeof item[key] === "string" && item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
    )
});
```

**EDIT: I am sorry, my bad. I have a list of objects.**
[image]

An object:

```
0: {…}
external_urls: Object { spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5" }
followers: Object { href: null, total: 14620829 }
genres: Array(5) [ "alternative rock", "funk metal", "funk rock", … ]
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5"
id: "0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5"
images: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
name: "Red Hot Chili Peppers"   ​​
popularity: 86   ​​
type: "artist"
uri: "spotify:artist:0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5"
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

---

**EDIT: This comes close, but doesn't work as expected:**

```
 const filtered = matches.filter(match => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${query}`, 'gi');
        return match.name.match(regex);
      });
```

Doesn't work: **red hot chili peppers**.

Comment: No need for this: `Object.keys(item)` and `item[key] === "string"` as its an array of string

Comment: @Rajesh, how do you mean?

Comment: what is `item` object in your code?

Comment: Give your object in code format please

Comment: I am getting these objects from the Spotify API.

Comment: Code worked fine for me in both cases "red" and "red hot" with a sample object. You should provide the object you got.

Comment: I have a input where I type. Now, every time I type something, suggestions appear, and out of these suggestions I'd like to continue and narrow down depending on what's in the input right now.

Comment: @AlbinM Your regex does not catches the string: https://regex101.com/r/KpUErd/1. Also, why do you have `.join("")` in regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented:

> No need for this: Object.keys(item) and item[key] === "string" as its an array of string

Your structure is an array of string. So you can directly consume the value and use String methods to validate it

If you have a complex data structure, like nested objects, then using `Object.keys` and then looping on them makes more sense as you do not know what keys you might need.

```js
const query = "red hot";
const matches = [
    "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
    "Dua Lipa",
    "X&Y",
    "Viva la Vida or Death and All His Friends"
];

const filteredList = matches
  .filter((match) => match.toLowerCase().includes(query))
  
console.log(filteredList)
```

You can even use Regex for this. This will allow you to ignore `toLowerCase()` call for every iteration

```js
var list = [{
  external_urls: {
    spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5"
  },
  followers: {
    href: null,
    total: 14620829
  },
  genres: ["alternative rock", "funk metal", "funk rock"],
  href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5",
  id: "0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5",
  name: "Red Hot Chili Peppers",
  popularity: 86,
  type: "artist",
  uri: "spotify:artist:0L8ExT028jH3ddEcZwqJJ5"
}]
const query = 'red hot'
const regex = new RegExp(query, 'gi')
const filteredList = list
  .filter((item) => regex.test(item.name))
console.log(filteredList)
```

Comment: @AlbinM Updated the answer with sample code. Your regex is incorrect. I suggest you use Regex101 to validate it

Comment: Rajesh, I solved it. Differently. Appreciate your input.